# Take action after standard events action is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, jquery-events

I need perform some action *after* standard action is completed. Something opposite to `event.preventDefault()`

This is example what I need:

```
$contentEditable.on('paste', function (event) {

  event.doWhatYouNeedToDo();

  // here I will use `range` object to grab cursor position
  // and take some additional actions with inserted text

});
```

Here is example how event works: https://jsfiddle.net/5emcf8rw/

I need somewhere handle *new* text, after standard action (text change) is performed

Here is solution suggested by @A. Wolff

```
$contentEditable.on('paste', function (event) {
  setTimeout(function () {
      // do whatever you want here
  }.bind(this), 0);
});
```

Can we be sure that timeout function is fired *after* standard action is completed?

Comment: By saying $contentEditable.on('paste', function (event) {, You are adding an additional callback along with the default callback for the event. So when you register the event handler you are doing the "doWhatYouNeedToDo"

Comment: I think you are wrong
https://jsfiddle.net/5emcf8rw/

Comment: whats the expected behavior you are looking for.

Comment: just a sec. editing question

Comment: @kakabomba So what's wrong with delaying it as in posted answer??? https://jsfiddle.net/5emcf8rw/1/  Paste event is fired before pasted data is pasted, there is no event 'pasted' so...

Comment: But are you just looking for paste event? Why not using `input` event otherwise?

Comment: Yes, thanks for mentioning `input` message, i will try it. Though asked question is for me much more wide than in provided example, and it is good to know answer in general case

Comment: @A.Wolff I think your solution deal with much more subtle question: how javascript is "asynchronous". Can binded in timeout function code be runed until current "digest" cycle is not finished? Sorry for naive terminology. I guess answers is "not asynchronous" and "No"

Comment: @kakabomba It could be browser/OS dependant but AFAIK a timeout put new event in the event queue so would be called once any previous event has returned

Comment: @A.Wolff in such case you solution is 100% safe

Comment: @kakabomba 100%, well i said it could be browser/OS dependant so...(let's say 99% safe). I find this link from John Resig which is quite interresting: http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

Answer (score 2):

You can delay it a little using a timeout:

```
$contentEditable.on('paste', function (event) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        // do whatever you want here
    }.bind(this), 0);
});
```

Comment: I don't know any better

Comment: I have complex dom tree, i CAN'T know how long standard actions is

Comment: It should always take less time than the timeout callback to be fired